# How to add variables and link them to a combobox from an external file?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a program where the user can choose a "class" of ships based off a combobox. Currently all the stats and classes are hard coded into the program. The problem is I want to be able to add extra ship types as needed. Preferably in a simple way that my friend (who knows almost nothing about code) and also add ships (the plan is once I finish, I'll give a copy to him to use). Each ship uses a name and 3 stats. The current hardcoded codes I have is -

```
private void cmb_Class_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        shipClass = (cmb_Class.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
        if (shipClass == "Scout")
        {
            attack = 6;
            engine = 10;
            shield = 8;
        }
        if (shipClass == "Warship")
        {
            attack = 10;
            engine = 6;
            shield = 8;
        }
        if (shipClass == "Cargo")
        {
            attack = 8;
            engine = 6;
            shield = 10;
        }
        if (shipClass == "Starliner")
        {
            attack = 6;
            engine = 8;
            shield = 10;
        }
        if (shipClass == "Transport")
        {
            attack = 8;
            engine = 10;
            shield = 6;
        }
        if (shipClass == "Luxury")
        {
            attack = 8;
            engine = 8;
            shield = 8;
        }

        lbl_Attack.Content = attack;
        lbl_Engine.Content = engine;
        lbl_Shield.Content = shield;
    }
```

The items in the combobox cmb_Class is all hardcoded into the WPF forms xml and the labels are just how I'm showing the stats.

Bonus issue: I can just make a secondary file for a similar group of "species" and their stats (yes, it's a sci-fi RPG type thing), but if there's a simple way to make them all in the same file, that'd be great.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sorry, but your questions sounds like "what is xml and how to use it", which is too broad. There are tons of tutorials both here and over the internet. You can write to ANY text file format manually or just deserialize your settings. It seems like you didn't actually make any effort to do it on your own.

Comment: Well the problem isn't so much getting an xml to read and such, rather making the combobox selection also load the variables.

Comment: One way you can solve your problem is to create database with table ship and 3 fields(attack, engine, shield). in this case when programm will be loaded, you can load all your existing ships to something like ObservableCollection<Ship>, that will be binded to combobox. If you would like to add new ship, you will need to create a button(create ship) and a form where you will be able to enter ship stats and save to database. After save you can reload values in observableCollection.

Comment: Instead of keeping ship names in your combobox, use ships collections as a data binding source to it and operate on objects collection, not on string literals. Your ship class should contain attack, engine and shield properties, and then it'd be easy to operate on such items, especially to save them and read to/from the file with serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, I am new to xml, so I don't suppose there's a way you can give me a bit of an example how to implement this in a way that'd work for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you might like to use. it's not using XML, it's using CSV but you can easily extend it.

first you'll need a class to represent your ships, like below.

```
public class Ship
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int Engine { get; set; }
    public int Shield { get; set; }
}
```

After this you'll need a way to read your ships from some sort of data source: file, DB, etc. this source can change ofter so you'll be better of abstracting this behind an interface like below.

```
interface IShipRepository
{
    List<Ship> GetShips();
}
```

After you decide where you'll get the ships from you can write that in an implementation of the IShipRepository interface. The code below shows how to read it from a CSV file.

```
public class CSVShipRepository : IShipRepository
{
    private readonly string filePath;
    public CSVShipRepository(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
    public List<Ship> GetShips()
    {
        var res = new List<Ship>();
        try
        {
            string fileData;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                fileData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //class, attack, engine, shield
            string[] lines = fileData.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (first)
                {//jump over the first line (the CSV header line)
                    first = false; continue;
                }
                string[] values = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                    .Select(p=>p.Trim()).ToArray();
                if (values.Length != 4) continue;

                var ship = new Ship() { 
                    Class=values[0],
                    Attack=int.Parse(values[1]),
                    Engine = int.Parse(values[2]),
                    Shield = int.Parse(values[3]),
                };

                res.Add(ship);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error reading file: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

all you have to do now is to use this CSVShipRepository in your code behind. we'll use a little data binding for this like below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IShipRepository repository = new CSVShipRepository("d:\\test_data.csv");
    private List<Ship> ships;
    private Ship selectedShip;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Ship> Ships
    {
        get
        {
            if (ships == null)
                ships = repository.GetShips();
            return ships;
        }
    }
    public Ship SelectedShip
    {
        get { return selectedShip; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedShip == value) return;
            selectedShip = value;
            NotifyChanged("SelectedShip");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

the corresponding XAML is below.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Ships}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShip, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Class}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedShip.Attack}" Margin="3" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedShip.Engine}" Margin="3" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding SelectedShip.Shield}" Margin="3" />
```

hope this is what you need. it's simpler than XML since your friend doesn't know code. and here is some sample data

```
class, attack, engine, shield
demo, 1, 2, 3
demo2, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: Now that's some comprehensive answer!